# Dynamic router name for magento controller

Tags: magento

How would I go about creating a custom module that has a controller with an action name that is dynamic, in the sense that it can be configured by the user in the admin area at will and be automatically updated in the custom module?

Comment: Can you show us the results of your research so far, so that we are not duplicating effort attempting to answer your question with things you've already discovered?

Comment: Also, what does "best" mean?  What are your criteria for success?

Comment: Hi Robert: is theoretical currently. My conclusion currently is to hook in to adminhtml form save event and update core_url_rewrite with new name user has selected. I have nothing concrete to display, simply trying to get input from experienced magento developers who can offer good advice. Apologies if this has offended you. Maybe I should delete the question and come back to stackoverflow when I have some solutions to show?

Comment: I'm not offended.  But SO isn't really an advice column.  I will try editing your question to make it less "soft."

Comment: Edit complete.  Is this what you're really after?

Answer (score 2):

You can override this method in your controller:

```
public function getActionMethodName($action)
{
    return 'indexAction';
}

public function indexAction()
{
    //action name
    var_dump($this->getRequest()->getActionName());
 }
```

Then always will go to the index action, where you can use the original action name as a parameter.

then:

http://mysite/mymodule/mycontroller/im-dracula-blablabla

Will work!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can approach this by using magic php method `__call` on your controller.

I assumed that you store your action name in a Magento config named 'mymodule/controller/action', so you can get the value using :

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule/controller/action');
```

Then you have the controller for example Mymodule/controllers/TestController.php

And you add the method in that controller like this :

```
public function __call($method, $arg) {
     if ($method == Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule/controller/action')) {
           //Do whatever you want
     }
}
```

This will make your controller //Do whatever you want when you accessing it using the action you specified in the config. The basic idea is like that. Hope this helps.