# Magento Custom Router Lost Layout Object

Tags: magento

It seems like everything is being properly configured and I can get the output that I want but I would prefer not echoing the layout object directly from my controller:

Here is what Im working with
config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <ALS_Bestselling>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </ALS_Bestselling>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <bestselling>
                <class>ALS_Bestselling_Model</class>
            </bestselling>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <bestselling>
                <class>ALS_Bestselling_Block</class>
            </bestselling>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <bestselling>
                <class>ALS_Bestselling_Helper</class>
            </bestselling>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <als_bestselling>
                    <file>bestselling.xml</file>
                </als_bestselling>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <default>
        <web>
            <routers>
                <bestselling_router>
                    <area>frontend</area>
                    <class>ALS_Bestselling_Controller_Router</class>
                </bestselling_router>
            </routers>
        </web>
        <shorturls>
        </shorturls>
    </default>
</config>
```

and

```
#File: Controller/Router.php

<?php    
class ALS_Bestselling_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract
{

    private static $_module = 'bestsellers';
    private static $_realModule = 'ALS_Bestselling';
    private static $_controller = 'index';
    private static $_controllerClass = 'ALS_Bestselling_Controller_Index';
    private static $_action = 'view';


    public function initControllerRouters($observer)
    {
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('bestselling', $this);
    }

    public function collectRoutes()
    {
        // nothing to do here
    }



    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $front = $this->getFront();
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        if(!substr($identifier,0,strlen('bestsellers')) == 'bestsellers'){
            return false;
        }else{
            //$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite');
            $route_params = str_replace ( "bestsellers/" , "" , $identifier );
            $rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite');
            $rewrite->setStoreId(1);
            $rewrite->loadByRequestPath($route_params);
            $category_route = $rewrite->getIdPath();

            //If no route exists for category send to a different router
            if(!$category_route != ""){
                return false;
            }//Otherwise send the parameters to the request
            else{
                $id = str_replace ( "category/" , "" , $category_route );
                $this->_request->setParam('id',$id);
            }

        $this->_setRequestRoute();
        $this->_dispatch();
        return true;
        }
    }
    protected function _setRequestRoute()
    {
        $this->_request->setModuleName(self::$_module);
        $this->_request->setControllerName(self::$_controller);
        $this->_request->setActionName(self::$_action);
        $this->_request->setControllerModule(self::$_realModule);

    }
    protected function _dispatch()
    {
        $this->_request->setDispatched(true);
        $controller = Mage::getControllerInstance(self::$_controllerClass, $this->_request, $this->_response);
        $controller->dispatch(self::$_action);
    }
}
```

and

```
File: Controller/Index.php

     class ALS_Bestselling_Controller_Index extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{   
    public function viewAction(){
            $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
            $layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();
            $render = $layout->getBlock('root')->toHtml();
            echo $render;
        }

    }
```

The previous works but the following:

```
$update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
$update->addHandle('default');
$this->renderLayout();
```

throws an error Call to a member function appendBody() on a non-object.

Is this how I am suppose to do this or is there something missing from the recipe?

Comment: Maybe some of you are wondering how this might benefit someone.
Here is how this works. Imagine you want to show some information tied back to a particular category for example (best selling products, faq's, product reviews, top ranked) but you want to have a unique url. You could do something like category/?showme=bestselling

That is ugly. For seo purposes you probably would want to do /bestselling/supplements/probiotics

This router grabs everything after bestselling and checks it to see if its a category and then sends the category id to your controller. Still working on a solution.

Comment: What's the line number/call-stack for the `appendBody` on a non-object exception?

Comment: Alan If necessary, I will back trace my work to answer your question but I was actually able to do this a much more appropriate way. Let me know. Here is a link to the post where I answered my own question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691586/force-magento-to-always-use-single-controller-for-module/15709618#15709618

Comment: As an added bonus I am now able to use Alan's Commercebug module - A must have (Seriously) for any Magento developer. It wasn't working with the broken method shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Custom routing classes are on the fringe of what most developers do with Magento — the standard approach would be to [setup a standard module controller with a frontname of `bestselling`](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world), or  create your feature in a  non-seo friendly way and then create a rewrite entity/object to SEO-ify it.

I, however, have a soft spot for custom routing objects, even if there's little in the way of best community practices behind them.  Without a line number, it sounds like your exception

> Call to a member function appendBody() on a non-object

comes from the following code

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php

$this->getResponse()->appendBody($output);
```

Given the definition for `getResponse`

```
public function getResponse()
{
    return $this->_response;
}
```

It sounds like your controller object doesn't have a proper response object set.

Looking at your controller instantiation code

```
$controller = Mage::getControllerInstance(self::$_controllerClass, $this->_request, $this->_response);
```

You're referencing a `$this->_response` property — but your router class and the abstract router class don't have this property.  It's impossible to say based on what you've posted, but this is probably your problem.  Take a look at how the standard router's  match method does it.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
//...
$controllerInstance = Mage::getControllerInstance($controllerClassName, $request, $front->getResponse());
```

So, use the front-controller object to grab the response object, pass that into the `getCongrollerInstance` factory method, and you should be good to go (or at least onto the next problem)